# Outlook message with inserted picture from command line

Tags: command-line, outlook

I often generate figure files (*.png) that I need to email to my coworkers. The communication is better if the image is embedded in the message body rather than attached. We all use Microsoft Outlook. It would make my life simpler if I could use the command line to open a new outlook message with a specified picture inserted in the body. The following command opens a new message and attaches the figure file,

```
outlook.exe /c ipm.note /a c:\temp\test.png
```

But instead I want the figure embedded in the body of the message. Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Tools -> Options -> Mail Format. Change it to Rich Text instead of HTML. Once the default Mail body has been changed if you run your command line the Attachments will be embedded in the mail's body.

Comment: Great, thanks. One more question: When the new message is opened, there is a link to the image (labeled test.png) but I can't see the image. If there is a way to open a new message with the image inline (i.e. visible in the body, like Insert > Picture), please let me know.

Comment: Well I tried on my computer. I didn't get any link. I got the attachment icon which when I double clicked opened the picture. I'll keep look though.

Comment: So when you double click the icon, you don't see the image? But I see your point. You want your image to get displayed like those spam email flyers ;). It must be some kind of configuration in the Tools. I'll see what I can find.